# How to get the output with exactly 4 digits by adding zeros?

Tags: python

I want to print the output with 4 digits.

For example, with `16/2`, the output should be `0008`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> '{:04d}'.format(16/2)
'0008'
```

The string format `04d` means:

```
0 -- fill spaces with 0
4 -- width should be 4 (though can be greater if the input requires it)
d -- format the input as an integer
```

For more information on the format string syntax, see [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: @JonClements: Is that just personal preference or is there a reason?

Comment: @drewk For single items I find it reads more naturally... you're formatting a value to be xyz... Not, having a string with items of a certain format from certain parameters

Answer (score 6):

[`str.zfill()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) is better suited for this:

```
>>> str(16/2).zfill(4)
'0008'
```

---

> `str.zfill(width)`
>
> Return the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of length *width*. A sign prefix is handled correctly. The original string is returned if width is less than or equal to `len(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

And to be complete, the older style:

```
In [1]: '%04d' % (16 / 2)
Out[1]: '0008'
```

The "04d" is the same as in @unutbu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.rjust`:

```
>>> str(16/2).rjust(4, '0')
'0008'
```